# How to install dart sass on Fedora 37?

Tags: css, sass

I'm having trouble installing Dart Sass on my Fedora 37 system. I've followed the official documentation and watched multiple tutorials, but I'm still encountering an error.

On the official [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/install/) lang site they say:

> You can install Sass on Windows, Mac, or **Linux** by downloading the
> package for your operating system from GitHub and adding it to your
> PATH. That’s all—there are no external dependencies and nothing else
> you need to install.

I carefully followed the installation steps:

1. Downloaded the correct dard-sass archive, which in the case of my operating system (Fedora 37) was dart-sass-1.70.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
2. Then I extracted the files to **~/opt/dart-sass** folder
3. Added `"export PATH="/opt/dart-sass:$PATH"` line to .bashrc file to add the extracted directory to my PATH.
4. Then I run `"source ~/.bashrc"` to apply the changes

However, when I ran the `"sass --version"` command, I received the following error:

```
qemu-aarch64-static: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory
```

I've done some research and attempted to install **binfmt-support**, but the error persists. Could someone please help me understand why I'm seeing this error and how I can resolve it and start using Sass?